# Django: Class to log a mail error

Tags: python, django, django-logging

I'm trying to follow the code for Django Unleashed and occasionally (by which I mean often) I have problems to understand the code in full. Here is an exaple of a function that is suppose to log errors when a certain mail does not sent. It is part of a login system.

```
    def log_mail_error(self, **kwargs):
    msg_list = [
        'Activation email did not send.\n',
        'from_email: {from_email}\n'
        'subject: {subject}\n'
        'message: {message}\n',
    ]
    recipient_list = kwargs.get(
        'recipient_list', [])
    for recipient in recipient_list:
        msg_list.insert(
            1, 'recipient: {r}\n'.format(
                r=recipient))
    if 'error' in kwargs:
        level = ERROR
        error_msg = (
            'error: {0.__class__.__name__}\n'
            'args: {0.args}\n')
        error_info = error_msg.format(
            kwargs['error'])
        msg_list.insert(1, error_info)
    else:
        level = CRITICAL
    msg = ''.join(msg_list).format(**kwargs)
    logger.log(level, msg)
```

I have a very hard time with one part:

```
error_msg = (
            'error: {0.__class__.__name__}\n'
            'args: {0.args}\n')
        error_info = error_msg.format(
            kwargs['error'])
```

I simply don't see where this 0.**class**.**name** comes from. What is the zero suppose to mean? There is no object or class called zero in the project. Also I dont really understand the formatting of the error_msg. Potentially I have two fields with {} {} where I could fit "kwargs['error']" but I only have one value to fit into two places for string formatting. But then agian, why the pain with {0.__class [...]} if its just meant to be a placeholder? There is something going on that I dont quite understand. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the [format mini language spec](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#formatspec) you'll notice that formatting a string can allow for passing the order of the received parameters. For example

```
'{0} and {1}'.format('foo', 'bar') # outputs foo and bar 
'{1} and {0}'.format('foo', 'bar') # outputs bar and foo
```

This simply means that the code is specifying that the parameter used to expand the format expression should be the first one passed

Since the actual `error` object is not defined in your code, i can only assume it's of a type that has a `args` property attached to it. 
In other words, the string outputs the type of the error and any parameters it was built with